# Capacitor bank with variable speed motor

Tags: motor, speed, fluid-pump, reactive-power

I have a set of three pumps (power ~100 kW) with variable speed AC motors and I would like to know the best option(s) to reduce the cost of reactive energy.

For instance, would it make sense to install a capacitor bank in the electrical cabinet?

Comment: Condensators? You mean capacitors, don't you?  What kind of motors? DC? Brushed? Brushless? AC? Three-Phase?

Comment: I think an issue with 100kW engines justifies getting an experienced engineer on location.

Comment: I will definitely get an experienced engineer on site. But at this stage, I am trying to find out about the options available. What I mean by condensators is indeed a capacitator bank (a more general term may be "compensator" for reactive energy). Now, the three motors are identical: AC induction (asynchronous) motor.

Comment: What's a condensator?  Is that like a resistorator or inductornator?  In any case, we do real world electrical engineering here and don't deal with unicorns or mythical electronic parts.

Comment: They're three-phase, driven by VFDs, or are they DC motors driven by PWM? Why might you think that a capacitor bank might help?

Comment: I guess this forum is also open to non-native English speakers, is not it? So my question is simply the following: can capacitors be used with an AC variable speed motor equipped with a frequency regulator? The idea behind is to reduce the consumption of reactive energy and the amount of the electricity bill for a pumping station.

Comment: Three-phase, driven by variable-frequency drive.

Comment: [This press release](http://www04.abb.com/GLOBAL/seitp/seitp202.nsf/viewunid/57D1C4FC9FB087F885256D420065AF11/$file/Power+Factor+Improved+Via+AC+Drives+-+Release.pdf) says: When AC variable speed drives are used, power-factor-correction capacitors should not be used, because it is usually unnecessary. Side note: it can actually reverse the power factor.

Comment: The press release is very clear indeed. Then, what other option(s) could be explored to reduce the consumption of reactive energy?

Comment: You could add a capacitor bank at the building's entry point.

Comment: The press release says: "At the plant level, the power factor correction can be accomplished by using power-factor-correction capacitors,or by using variable speed AC drives. When AC drives are used, power-factor-correction capacitors should not be used, because it is usually unnecessary, and because drive harmonics could damage power factor capacitors." Then, I am not sure to understand: what is the difference between installing a capacitor bank at the plant level and, as you suggest, the buidling entry's point? The two opinions sound contradictory.

Comment: @OlinLathrop in some regions the local and proper name for a capacitor is a condensator. There is no reason for such a negative response as yours.

Comment: Do you have a means of measuring the reactive power? Do you have the means of verifying the actual cause of the reactive power? In other words how big is the problem really and are you sure the motors are the cause?

Comment: @jipp: Long ago, and still in some automotive and other niche applications, a capacitor was called a *condenser*, but "condensator" is just babble.

Comment: @OlinLathrop It is just a false friend. In some languages condensator is the real component and capacitor is the ideal approximation.

Comment: The problem is serious enough, because I understood that reactive energy was accounting for almost of the electricity bill paid by the station. I am not sure whether the motors are the cause, but they are the main consumer of electricity in the pumping station. Further, you are certainly right: I first need to check whether there are electrical meters for active, reactive and maximum power. If the motors are the cause, I then want to find out whether a capacitor bank installed at the entry point in the electrical cabinet can help to reduce the cost of the electricity bill.

Comment: @OlinLathrop if you are so keen on using perfect terminology, could you at least set an example by spelling my nickname correctly?

Comment: Sorry for having created this trouble. But I would like to add the following: I have been working overseas for quite a long time now with multi-cultural and multi-disciplinary teams: misunderstandings due to language barriers and diversity of technical backgrounds are unavoidable. Best is then to show patience and good will to achieve a proper collaboration. Coming back to the core of my question, any further comment will be appreciated.

Comment: @jippie The comment system lets you just use the first three characters of someone's name so I don't think Olin was misspelling it.

Comment: I have done further search and it seems that the provision of a capacitor bank in the electrical cupboard, plus the type of connection used (star or delta), can help saving on reactive and peak energy. I would be interested in hearing your comments on these two options.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to reduce the displacement power factor of your plant, you've already accomplished that by the use of variable frequency drives. The line will no longer see the current lag that it would see if the inductance of the motor was placed directly across the line.

However, VFDs have other issues; a standard six-pulse front-end VFD will have the usual rectifier current profile, which doesn't look at all like a sine wave. Your harmonics will likely be quite bad, which you may also be charged for. If you want to correct that, you'll need a filter of some kind. Most VFD manufacturers offer models with active front-ends, which pull sine wave currents out of the line. Many companies also offer passive harmonic filters.

Now, there are other cases where it may make sense to install capacitors in your drive cabinet. If your application is very cyclical, motoring then braking, you might use a large bank of capacitors to store the braking energy for reuse during the next motoring cycle. But that can cause issues with your VFD's precharge circuit. And regenerating that braking energy back to the power line is often more cost effective, depending on the details. Adding capacitance to the DC bus can also make your harmonics worse.